# rsync via ssh from behind proxy - advice request

Tags: server, ssh, proxy, rsync

I need to rsync to a server on the Internet from a server behind a squid proxy. My resource got me some way, but I’m stuck and would appreciate constructive comments.
IP below is on actual server IP’s, just place holders.

- Server OS on both sides: Ubuntu 18.04 server
- Local server IP `10.2.2.9`
- Proxy server IP `192.168.3.5:3128`
- Proxy allow access on per IP base for server (so no username and password)
- Local server http & https proxy setting in `/etc/environment` file
- Remote server IP `40.38.6.4`
- Remote SSH port `2211`
- Remote SSH is set to key pair authentication

Command proposed from multiple searches, but is not working:

```
rsync -azpogve  "ssh -p 2211" /var/master master@40.38.6.4:/var/master --delete-after --ignore-errors
```

Looking on the proxy server log, we cannot see the local server even attempting to connect.

Comment: Please show the proxy-related variables declared in the env config file - Must declare a rsync proxy var `RSYNC_PROXY=user:password@proxyhost:port`

Comment: Does the `ssh` command work? Without trying to `rsync`.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, no the ssh fails with a time out and we do not see any activity on the proxy log.

Comment: @cmak.fr, I have added the rsync_proxy, but it is still not working.

Comment: @cmak.fr, PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,10.2.0.0"
http_proxy="http://192.168.2.5:3128/"
https_proxy="http://192.168.3.5:3128/"
HTTP_PROXY="http://192.168.3.5:3128/"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://192.168.3.5:3128/"
ftp_proxy="http://192.168.3.5:3128/"
rsync_proxy=192.168.3.5:3128

Comment: Var names MUST be UPPERCASE

Comment: @cmak.fr, I change the rsync_proxy to uppercase, but it still fails. I think Eduardo has a point. the ssh command fails with time out.

Comment: @DeonOosthuizen If you don't get the `ssh` to work on its own, it's very unlikely that rsync will work. You should probably center your efforts in getting `ssh` command up and running.

Comment: So after some experimenting I have ssh working between the servers using `ssh -J 192.168.3.5 deon@40.38.6.4 -p 2211` This still ask for password. I have ssh keys, but have not configured sshd to use keys. I also found sshpass to send the password to ssh command line, but then I get dropped back to the local server console after the connection was made and closed.